# Beamer Metropolis top bar Height and Transparency

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, beamer-metropolis

For the beamer metropolis theme:

How to make the top bar taller? and is there a way to make it transparent (perhaps using TiKz)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the size via

```
\setlength{\metropolis@frametitle@padding}{5ex}
```

or

```
\setlength{\moloch@frametitle@padding}{5ex}
```

if you use the `moloch` theme, a more modern fork of the metropolis theme.

And the opacity can be changed like this (adjust `\pgfsetfillopacity{0.3}` to whatever value you like):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\makeatletter
\setlength{\moloch@frametitle@padding}{5ex}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \pgfsetfillopacity{0.3}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=\paperwidth,%
      sep=0pt,%
      leftskip=\moloch@frametitle@padding,%
      rightskip=\moloch@frametitle@padding,%
    ]{frametitle}%
  \pgfsetfillopacity{1}
  \moloch@frametitlestrut@start%
  \insertframetitle%
  \nolinebreak%
  \moloch@frametitlestrut@end%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \pgfsetfillopacity{1}
}

\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]